# In Shiny text input, need updated text to align so that overflow text appears right-aligned

Tags: r, shiny, direction, text-align

I've created a Shiny app that adds text either by typing in text to an input field or by pressing various buttons that add text to the input field. I've contained the input field in a div that has direction:ltr as a style, so when text is typed in it appears on the right as wanted. However, when the text is updated using updateTextInput and the buttons that add text, the overflow text eventually disappears on the right because it is left aligned. The direction style is obviously not helping in this regard, and it doesn't help to specify text-align:left either. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
strings <- c("on", "recommend", "tolerably", "my", "belonging", "or", "am", "mutual", "has", "cannot", "indeed", "now", "mutual", "jennings", "offended")

string.list = NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
        rnum <- sample(1:length(strings), 1)
        string.list <- c(string.list, strings[rnum])
}
string.list <- unlist(string.list)

# Define UI 
ui = (fluidPage(align = "center",
        div(textInput(inputId = "inputText", label = "Enter your text here:"), style="direction:ltr"),
        #display dynamic UI
        uiOutput("my_button", inline=TRUE),
        uiOutput("button2", inline=TRUE),
        uiOutput("button3", inline=TRUE),
        p(verbatimTextOutput('text'), width = 200)
))


server = function(input, output, session){
        #set up reactive text
        text <- reactiveValues()
        text$string.list <- string.list


        #make dynamic button
        output$my_button <- renderUI({
                actionButton("action1", label = text$string.list[1])
        })

        output$button2 <- renderUI({
                actionButton("action2", label = text$string.list[2])
        })

        output$button3 <- renderUI({
                actionButton("action3", label = text$string.list[3])
        })

        output$text <- renderText({
                text$text <- c(text$mainText, input$inputText)
        })


        observeEvent(input$action1, {
                text$text <- paste(text$text, text$string.list[1])
                output$text <- renderText({
                        text$text
                })
                updateTextInput(session = session, inputId = "inputText", value = text$text)
                string.list = character(0)
                for (i in 1:3) {
                        rnum <- sample(1:length(strings), 1)
                        string.list <- c(string.list, strings[rnum])
                }
                new.strings <- unlist(string.list)
                text$string.list <- new.strings
        })

        observeEvent(input$action3, {
                text$text <- paste(text$text, text$string.list[3])
                output$text <- renderText({
                        text$text
                })
                updateTextInput(session = session, inputId = "inputText", value = text$text)
                string.list = character(0)
                for (i in 1:3) {
                        rnum <- sample(1:length(strings), 1)
                        string.list <- c(string.list, strings[rnum])
                }
                new.strings <- unlist(string.list)
                text$string.list <- new.strings
        })

        observeEvent(input$action2, {
                text$text <- paste(text$text, text$string.list[2])
                output$text <- renderText({
                        text$text
                })
                updateTextInput(session = session, inputId = "inputText", value = text$text)
                string.list = character(0)
                for (i in 1:3) {
                        rnum <- sample(1:length(strings), 1)
                        string.list <- c(string.list, strings[rnum])
                }
                new.strings <- unlist(string.list)
                text$string.list <- new.strings
        })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: A reproducible example please.

Comment: I've added the basic code for the app, thanks